# Exploratory factor analysis with predictor variable?

Tags: factor-analysis

Here's the experimental design:

Participant takes a drug, and fills out a survey at various time points. The survey is designed to measure affect, by asking the participant to respond to assorted emotion adjectives on a seven-point scale.
The responses can probably be described by two factors: energy, and pleasantness. I would like to know how the drug affects these variables over time.

So far, I have performed exploratory factor analysis on the survey items. Then, I used nonlinear regression with the factor scores, to estimate the time course of the drug's effects.

I feel like this isn't the ideal way to analyze the data, because the drug could influences multiple latent variables, making them correlated.

How should I handle this? I don't have any experience with structural equation modelling, but I'll learn if I have to. It seems like I'd want a model where time nonlinearly affects two unobserved variables (energy and pleasantness), both of which affect the response to each survey item.

Am I on the right track? How bad would it be to just do a factor analysis, and use the scores in a nonlinear regression?